# Adding Label to JPanel and Add method not suggested in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jpanel, jlabel

This may seem a very newbie question but I can't seem to find answers for this situation. 
The [How to Use Panels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html) tutorial says there is an `add()` method in `JPanel` but I cannot implement it in my code.

```
public class JPanelTest extends AbstractView {
   private final JPanel panel;

 public JPanelTest () {
   this.panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
 }

 private void initComponents() {
   JLabel label = new JLabel("label testing ");
   this.panel.add(label);
 }
}
```

The `AbstractView` is an abstract class that extends `JPanel` and implements `ViewSupport`, `PropertyChangeListener`.

In the last line of code `this.panel.add(label);` gives a compile error.
I don't see `Panel.add()` suggested in Eclipse.
The suggested add-related methods are `addAncestorListener`, `addNotify`, `addVetoableChangeListener`.

How can I not see a simple add method in the suggested box?
I am using 1.6 compile level of Eclipse. Would that make a difference?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you get the AbstractView? It is not a build in to Java SDK.

Answer (score 2):

You create the JPanel, panel, but add it to nothing. So yes, it is receiving the JLabel, but since neither the JLabel nor the panel JPanel are added to anything displayed by the main GUI window (a JFrame?) none get displayed.

Solution: either add the panel JPanel or the JLabel itself to the `this` object (which is hopefully added to the top level window/JFrame).

So either:

```
private void initComponents() {
   JLabel label = new JLabel("label testing ");
   this.panel.add(label);
   this.add(panel);
}
```

or

```
private void initComponents() {
   JLabel label = new JLabel("label testing ");
   // this.panel.add(label);
   this.add(label);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
It was not about failing to display it on GUI, but was more about why I got a compile error and eclipse didn't suggest a simple add method.
I copied your code and pasted it and compile error is gone.
It seems odd that does that in Eclipse.

Comment: @In-youngChoung: do you have your own class named `JPanel`? If so you would be confusing the compiler (and yourself).

Comment: @In-youngChoung: and if your question is about a compilation error (sorry for not looking at it fully), then always post the complete error message, not just a paraphrasing of it.

Comment: Yes you are correct. 
However, it was more of the compile error while typing and looking at the suggested method box that didn't include a simple add method.
Once I copied your code and pasted, it seems okay (no compile error).

Comment: I was wondering why, sometimes, eclipse doesn't include certain methods in the suggested box.

Comment: @In-youngChoung: I was correct about what specifically? Re why Eclipse.. it's because those methods are not available to the variable in question.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you get the AbstractView? It is not a build in to [Swing hierachy](http://www.javatpoint.com/java-swing).

Base on your class name maybe you want to extend `JPanel` instead of `AbstractView`

```
public class JPanelTest extends JPanel {
```